# Speech Service Token Duration Extension Issue

Tags: botframework, speech

I need to keep a Speech Service alive for a long period of time.
Speech Service tokens last 10 minutes by default.
Hence a service duration extension is required.
Thought about the following approaches:
1 - User token generation parameter that would allow its duration extension.
2 - Catch the token expiration exception in my code and request a new token whiteout forcing my bot to restart.
Couldn't find a solution for it yet though.
My bot app always break with a `failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available` message after the token expires.
Here is my bot code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>FTD Bit_Bot</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #fff; background-image: url('img/FTDBackground.jpg');">
    <div id="chatbot" role="main"
         data-cb-width="320px"
         data-cb-height="400px"
         data-cb-border="1px solid #ededed"
         data-cb-border-radius="0px"
         data-cb-background-color="white"
         data-cb-position="fixed"
         data-cb-right="40px"
         data-cb-bottom="100px"
         data-cb-zIndex="1"
         data-cb-bubble-background="rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.15)"
         data-cb-bubble-from-user-background="#e22e2c"
         data-cb-bubble-from-user-text-color="white"
         data-cb-bubble-max-width="600"
         data-cb-bot-avatar-image="http://demo.radical-thinking.net/bella/microsoft/chat-assets/img/Chat-in-day-Workshop-Icon.png"
         data-cb-hide-send-box="false"
         data-cb-hide-upload-button="true"
         data-cb-send-box-button-color="#e22e2c"
         data-cb-send-box-button-color-on-disabled="#CCC"
         data-cb-send-box-button-color-on-focus="#333"
         data-cb-send-box-button-color-on-hover="#333"
         data-cb-send-box-height="30"
         data-cb-suggested-action-text-color="black"
         data-cb-suggested-action-border="solid 2px #e22e2c"
         data-cb-suggested-action-height="30">
    </div>
    <!-- Include ajax library for speech service token request call -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include webchat client functionality (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) -->
    <!-- Change to the latest directory to stop the 'No renderer for this activity' error. However the avatar won't show -->
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
        var chatbot = document.getElementById('chatbot');

        // Style modifications
        const styleOptions = {

            // Colors
            bubbleBackground: chatbot.dataset.cbBubbleBackground,
            bubbleFromUserBackground: chatbot.dataset.cbBubbleFromUserBackground,
            bubbleFromUserTextColor: chatbot.dataset.cbBubbleFromUserTextColor,
            bubbleMaxWidth: parseInt(chatbot.dataset.cbBubbleMaxWidth), // maximum width of text message

            // Avatar
            botAvatarImage: chatbot.dataset.cbBotAvatarImage,
            userAvatarInitials: '',

            // Send box
            hideSendBox: JSON.parse(chatbot.dataset.cbHideSendBox),
            hideUploadButton: JSON.parse(chatbot.dataset.cbHideUploadButton),
            sendBoxButtonColor: chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxButtonColor,
            sendBoxButtonColorOnDisabled: chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxButtonColorOnDisabled,
            sendBoxButtonColorOnFocus: chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxButtonColorOnFocus,
            sendBoxButtonColorOnHover: chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxButtonColorOnHover,
            sendBoxHeight: parseInt(chatbot.dataset.cbSendBoxHeight),

            // Suggested actions
            suggestedActionTextColor: chatbot.dataset.cbSuggestedActionTextColor,
            suggestedActionBorder: chatbot.dataset.cbSuggestedActionBorder,
            suggestedActionHeight: parseInt(chatbot.dataset.cbSuggestedActionHeight),

        }
    </script>
    <script>
        var chatbot = document.getElementById("chatbot");

        //style tag start
        var script = {
            id: 'chatbotStyle',
            type: 'text/css',
            style: document.createElement('style'),
            content: '@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,600"); ::-webkit-scrollbar{width:10px}::-webkit-scrollbar-track{background:#f1f1f1}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background:#888}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{background:#555} #chatbot{ font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; position: fixed; right: 10px; bottom: 20px; text-align: center; } #chatbot img{ margin: auto; } #chatbot small{ display: block; font-size: 9px; } .initLaunchPad{ cursor: pointer; text-align: center; transition: .4s all; } .botHeader{min-height:40px;background:#ededed;border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;display:flex;justify-content:space-between;align-items:center;padding:4px} .botHeader img{float:left;width:32px;height:32px; border-radius:50%;background-color:#f9f9f9}.botHeader h5{float:left;padding:0!important;margin:4px 0 3px 6px} .botHeader h5 small{font-size: 12px;} .botHeader > div{width:40%;display:flex;align-items:center;text-align:left;height:32px} #botClose{cursor:pointer;font-size:12px;font-weight:600;padding:6px 8px;border-radius:4px;background-color:#e22e2c;color:#fff; } #botContainer{ display: none; border-radius: 8px; border:1px solid #cbcbcb; transition:.4s all; width: 310px; height: 420px; max-width:420px; max-height: 420px; margin-bottom: 4px; } #botBody{ height: 366px; } ',
            append: function () {
                this.style.type = this.type;
                this.style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.content));
                document.head.appendChild(this.style);
            }
        }; script.append();
        //style tag end

        //initLaunchPad started
        var initLaunchPad = document.createElement('div');
        initLaunchPad.classList.add('initLaunchPad');
        var initBotIcon = document.createElement('img');
        initBotIcon.src = "https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4876/39891228293_13c532f352_o.gif";
        initBotIcon.width = 86;
        initLaunchPad.appendChild(initBotIcon);
        chatbot.appendChild(initLaunchPad);

        $(function getSpeechAuthToken() {
            var params = {
                // Request parameters
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://brazilsouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken" + $.param(params),
                beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
                    // Request headers
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "XXXXXX");
                },
                type: "POST",
                // Request body
                data: "{body}",
            })
                .done(function (data) {
                    speechAuthToken = data;
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    alert("error");
                });
        });
        initBotIcon.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            initLaunchPad.style.display = "none";
            botContainer.style.display = "block";

            /*Call bot API*/
            (async function () {

                const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

                //Speech Service Token Generation
                const subscriptionKey = 'XXXXXX';
                const region = 'brazilsouth';
                let webSpeechPonyfillFactory;

                //Speech Service Setting
                webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
                    credentials: {
                        authorizationToken: speechAuthToken,
                        region: region
                    }
                });

                //Direct-Line BotToken Generation
                const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', { method: 'POST', headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + 'XXXXXX' } });
                const { token } = await res.json();

                window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
                    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
                    store,
                    userID: "User",
                    styleOptions,
                    locale: 'pt-BR',
                    selectVoice: (voices, activity) =>
                        activity.locale === 'pt-BR'
                            ? voices.find(({ name }) => /Daniel/iu.test(name))
                            : voices.find(({ name }) => /Daniel/iu.test(name)) ||
                            voices.find(({ name }) => /Daniel/iu.test(name)),
                    webSpeechPonyfillFactory
                }, document.getElementById('botBody'));
                document.querySelector('#botBody > *').focus();

                var mainTag = chatbot.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];
                mainTag.style.borderTop = chatbot.dataset.cbBorder;
            })().catch(err => console.error(err));

            //Bot Message Exchange Setting 
            const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
                if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                        payload: {
                            name: 'userName',
                            value: Paul
                        }
                    });                    
                }
                return next(action);
            });

        //initLaunchPad ended

        var botContainer = document.createElement('div');
        botContainer.id = "botContainer";

        var botHeader = document.createElement('div');
        botHeader.classList.add('botHeader');

        var botClose = document.createElement('a');
        botClose.id = "botClose";
        botClose.innerText = "X";
        botClose.title = "Close";
        botHeader.innerHTML = "<div><img src='" + chatbot.dataset.cbBotAvatarImage + "'/> <h5>Bit_Bot <small>FTD Educação</small> </div></h5>";
        botHeader.appendChild(botClose);

        botClose.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            initLaunchPad.style.display = "";
            botContainer.style.display = "none";
            return false;
        });

        botContainer.appendChild(botHeader);

        var botBody = document.createElement('div');
        botBody.id = "botBody";
        botContainer.appendChild(botBody);

        var poweredBy = document.createElement('div');
        poweredBy.innerHTML = "<small>Powered by <img src='http://ainetw.com/img/icon.png' width=12 /> AI Networks</small>";

        chatbot.appendChild(botContainer);
        chatbot.appendChild(poweredBy);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I unsuccessfully managed to catch the error in following parts of the code.
1) In the speech service setting.

```
 //Speech Service Setting
        try {
           webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
           credentials: {
               authorizationToken: speechAuthToken,
               region: region
           }
        });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error Speech Service');
            console.log(error);
            //Refreshes token
            getSpeechAuthToken();
            webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
                credentials: {
                    authorizationToken: speechAuthToken,
                    region: region
                }
            });
        }
```

2) In the Webchat setting.

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
            directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
            store,
            //userID: "Randomly Generated by the Webchat",
            styleOptions,
            locale: 'pt-BR',
            selectVoice: (voices, activity) =>
                activity.locale === 'pt-BR'
                    ? voices.find(({ name }) => /Daniel/iu.test(name))
                    : voices.find(({ name }) => /Daniel/iu.test(name)) ||
                    voices.find(({ name }) => /Daniel/iu.test(name)),
            webSpeechPonyfillFactory
        }, document.getElementById('botBody'));
        document.querySelector('#botBody > *').focus();

        var mainTag = chatbot.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];
        mainTag.style.borderTop = chatbot.dataset.cbBorder;
    })().catch(err =>
        {
            console.log('Error Webchat');
        console.log(error);
        //Refreshes token
        getSpeechAuthToken();
            if (err && err.status === 401) {
                speechAuthToken = speechAuthToken();
                webSpeechPonyfillFactory = window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
                    credentials: {
                        authorizationToken: speechAuthToken,
                        region: region
                    }
                 });
            }
        }
    );
```

How could we avoid the token expiration issue? 
Thx

Answer (score 0):

From the Cognitive Services Speech Service [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-speech-to-text#how-to-use-an-access-token),

> Each access token is valid for 10 minutes. You can get a new token at any time, however, to minimize network traffic and latency, we recommend using the same token for nine minutes.

In my setup, I run a "token" server locally (can be deployed, too), running Restify, that I make my various token generating API service calls from. In the Restify token server, I have setup my own APIs I can call from Web Chat. When I call my token server API, the service API is called, fetching the token, and returns it to Web Chat.

In this way, I solve two problems at once. One, my service's secret is safe on the server side and, two, I can setup a `setInterval()` that calls the API in question in Web Chat before the token would expire.

---

**tokenServer.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
const restify = require('restify');
const request = require('request');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const corsMiddleware = require('restify-cors-middleware');

const cors = corsMiddleware({
    origins: ['*']
});

const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: ENV_FILE });

// Create HTTP server.
const server = restify.createServer();
server.pre(cors.preflight);
server.use(cors.actual);
server.use(bodyParser.json({
    extended: false
}));

server.post('/speechservices/token', async (req, res) => {
    const options = {
        // method: 'POST',
        uri: `https://${ process.env.SPEECH_SERVICES_REGION }.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken`,
        headers: {
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': process.env.SPEECH_SERVICES_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY
        }
    };
    request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (!error && response.statusCode < 300) {
            body = { region: process.env.SPEECH_SERVICES_REGION, authorizationToken: body };
            res.send({
                authorizationToken: body.authorizationToken,
                region: body.region
            });
            console.log(`Someone requested a speech token...(${ response.statusCode })`);
        } else if (response.statusCode >= 400 && response.statusCode < 500) {
            res.send({ statusCode: response.statusCode, error: "CS's speech token API returned error" });
        } else if (response.statusCode >= 500) {
            res.status(response.statusCode);
            res.send({ statusCode: response.statusCode, error: "CS's speech token API couldn't be reached" });
        }
    });
});
```

**Web Chat** - I set the region value on the service side and simply return it with the token.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  const fetchPromise =  fetch( 
  `http://localhost:3500/speechservices/token`, { method: 'POST' } );

  return fetchPromise.then(async res => {
    if ( res.status === 200 ) {
      const { authorizationToken, region, error: error } = await res.json();
      credentials['authorizationToken'] = authorizationToken;
      credentials['region'] = region;

      return credentials;
    } else {
      console.log( `Speech Services: ${ error }` )
    }
  });
}, 540000); // Is set to 9 minutes
```

Hope of help!

Comment: Thx @Steven Kanberg. So how shall the setInterval function be called in the Webchat then? I tried this after configuring the token server (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7httI0vGRypfGLWywTyfQ?e=NlNXUZ)  but it didn't work..

Comment: I'm speaking with the primary dev of Web Chat and am waiting for a couple questions to get answered. When that happens, I'll update the above. In the meantime, can you tell me which version of Web Chat you are running (you can check this in the Elements tab in your browser's developer console by expanding the `<head>` element and looking at the scripts.

Comment: Also, why do you use ajax to get the speech token instead of fetch like is done for the direct line token?

Comment: Thx @Steven Kanberg. I'm using the following cdn setup:
Webchat: V4.8
CDN: https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js
Botframework: V4

Comment: Regarding the ajax usage no special reason for that. I just followed a sample code that used that approach. It should be replaced once our token generator service goes live. Suggestions are welcome.